# D3 rounding coordinates performance issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

All,

I am not sure this is a D3 issue per-se or if this is expected behaviour. I am generating a bostock spinning globe, which takes a bunch of geographical coordinates that are crunched by an algorithm to create desired projection. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3078L7x2/4/

The issue is that no matter how you try to limit the number of decimal points in the geographical coordinates, the output calculations by D3 land with an insanely large number of decimal points (see image below). I am no computer scientist but I am led to assume there must be a significant performance cost associated with this. The globe animation is juddery and uncomfortable as a result.

What would be the best way to reduce the number of `output decimal points`?

Thanks.

[image: Large number of decimal points]

Comment: You're correct in not being sure: that's not a D3 issue, that is the default behaviour of the path generator. I'd suggest you to forget about it. But, if you want know more about this or what improvements you can do, edit your question and add a *SVG* tag. Meanwhile, this is a good reading: https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/css-tricks.com/understanding-and-manually-improving-svg-optimization/amp/?client=ms-android-motorola

Comment: There's very little performance cost. Paths are stored as floats so whether values have 2 decimal places or 20 they take up 4 bytes. The cost of reading characters is not really significant compared to the cost of rendering.

Comment: What about the calculations performed on those lengthy decimals?